# Basis for field extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ with composite d

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

Every time I see an example of a basis for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ in my book, $d$ is prime. Is there a reason for this?

Let $d=p_1\times p_2$ where $p_1$ and $p_2$ are different primes, and $\sqrt{d} \not \in \mathbb{Q}$. Is the basis for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})=\{a+ b\sqrt{d} \mid a,b \in \mathbb{Q}\}$?

Thanks in advance

Edit:
I meant: the basis for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})=\{1, \sqrt{d}\}$ as pointed out in the answers. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is.${}{}$

Comment: $d$ shouldn't be a square (better square-free).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\{a + b\sqrt{d} \mid a, b \in \Bbb Q\}$ is **not** a basis for $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{d})$. It is not linearly independent. It contains $0$, for example.

One example for a $\Bbb Q$-basis for $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{d})$ is $\{1, \sqrt{d}\}$. This works not only for $d = p_1p_2$ (with $p_1 \neq p_2$) but also for any $d \in \Bbb Q$ which is not the square of a rational number. (How?)

Comment: Thanks!
Yes, I actually meant $\{1, \sqrt{d}\}$ and wrote the set of elements of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ by mistake